# Mincha as a Custom

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I was reviewing for shabbos in my Ezras Torah Luach (I read it twice in the Hebrew, and once in the English translation so I feel prepared for shul) and I noticed a subtle difference in the wording. For many other shabbosim, there is no particular mention of Mincha, or if there is, it is just to point out a change in the liturgy (such as whether or not we say Tzidkascha tzedek, as for Shabbos Mishpatim, page 90) and this is folded in to the last line fot the shacharis entry.

In some rare cases, the construction is different, with mincha having its own entry, with its order delineated, such as for Shabbos Acharei, page 131. In each case, there seems to be a hava amina that there is something special about mincha that requires clarification.

But for Shabbos Pekudei, the lashon is altered. In the entry for Shacharis, after the haftarah is listed, the text continues (page 97, but I haven't found a link to this on the Hebrew Books website), "Customary Mincha; three Aliyas in Parshas Vayikra."

If I recall correctly, the masoretic Hebrew says much the same thing (mincha kanoheg...). But I could not figure out what the hava amina would be that would make mincha worthy of any note. Then I looked at the lashon more carefully -- it reads "Customary". I haven't looked at the meforshim on this but it seems to be saying that the saying of mincha on that Shabbos is a minhag, though the hava amina would be that one is required to say mincha! Then, by listing the aliyos the text teaches us that even when mincha is a minhag, we can still lein from the torah! This DOES seem like a chiddush to me, but the text doesn't explain *why* this is the case.

Why would Shabbos Pekudei only have mincha as a minhag? Are there commentaries on this sefer which explain the logic used here?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Sidebar (non-Purim-type comment) - Why would Ezrat Torah calendar need to mention anything at all for p. Pekudeai as there is nothing special about that Shabbat. What am I missing, here?

Comment: @DanF that's actually what prompted the question but I realized that because (in a non-Purim sense) the book is edited inconsistently, that answer might just be "because."

Comment: Hmm ... so much for Ezrat Torah being an "ezra"!